# Can I make graphviz concentrate edges based on color?

Tags: graphviz

I have a directed graph where the color of the edges matters:

#### Current Diagram

```
digraph {
    splines=ortho
    node [shape=box];
    1 -> 4 [color="#51dbf4"];
    4 -> 7 [color="#51dbf4"];
    7 -> 1 [color="#ac043e"];
    7 -> 1 [color="#51dbf4"];
    1 -> 7 [color="#ac043e"];
}
```

[image: Current Graph]

I want to combine the maroon colored arrows to make the graph more clear.

#### Desired Diagram

```
digraph {
    splines=ortho
    node [shape=box];
    1 -> 4 [color="#51dbf4"];
    4 -> 7 [color="#51dbf4"];
    7 -> 1 [color="#ac043e" dir=both];
    7 -> 1 [color="#51dbf4"];
}
```

[image: Desired Graph]

However, this requires me to manually change each arrow that needs to be combined into a double-headed arrow. I wanted to merge these automatically. I tried using `concentrate=true` to make the arrows merge, but that kind of destroys the meaning of the graph:

#### Incorrect Diagram

```
digraph {
    splines=ortho
    concentrate=true
    node [shape=box];
    1 -> 4 [color="#51dbf4"];
    4 -> 7 [color="#51dbf4"];
    7 -> 1 [color="#ac043e"];
    7 -> 1 [color="#51dbf4"];
    1 -> 7 [color="#ac043e"];
}
```

[image: Incorrect Graph]

Graphviz insists on merging the arrows regardless of their color, which is not correct in this case because it kind of just obliterates most of the edges.

#### Question

For my use case, I have a large, code-generated graph with tons of edges and I don't want to manually change so many edges to be double-ended. Is there a way to specify to graphviz that I only want to merge edges of the same color? Like maybe I could tag each edge with a group ID and then it would only merge edges that have the same ID? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but this **gvpr** (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) program does what you want.
For each edge, it checks if a "reverse" edge exists, and if so checks if both have the same color.
If so, set **dir=both** & delete the "reverse" edge.

```
E{
  edge_t N2;
  N2=isEdge($.head, $.tail,"");
  if (N2!=NULL && N2.color==$.color){
    print("// bingo : ", $.name, " <--> ", N2.name);
    $.dir="both";
    delete($G, N2);
  }
}
```

And a (Linux) command line of
`gvpr -c -f single2double.gvpr myfile.gv | dot -Tpng >o.png`
Giving:
[image]

Comment: This is a super cool solution! But I am currently generating my graphs in a web browser using [Viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js) and I don't think that package provides a way to run `gvpr` in the browser. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: No other ideas at the moment.  Are you open to installing the Graphviz package on your computer?

Comment: This is to be used in an application that requires running in the frontend of a website, so installing it would not do any good. I did manage to solve my issue in this case by including the logic for detecting where the double-ended arrows should go in the graph generation code. But I'm going to accept this answer since it definitely answers the question and is a good answer even though it didn't quite do what I needed.